# Automated Screenshot Taking API

Tags: android, iphone, screenshot, webpage-screenshot

In Our company, we need to take screenshot of entire web site map, doing manually this job is a big pain. I have used Webdriver API (Selenium 2) to take screenshot on Browser but we have mobile web as well. Google chrome has device dimension setting to display a site as a mobile web site. Taking re sized browser screenshot is not possible in Google chrome. Not sure if its possible to take screenshot of Iphone, android phone or both virtual devices. Didn't find out a good answer after researching. I am trying to implement something which will take automated screenshot of any mobile webpage and save it to a specific directory based on URL. I prefer to use any JAVA library to do this but open for any suggestions.  Hoping for the best to get answer here.

Answer (score 1):

**From device using Robotium**

You can use robotium to take screenshots from a device. [From the Q&A at the Robotium project website](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/QuestionsAndAnswers):

> Can I take screenshots from inside of Robotium?
>
> Yes you can. Use takeScreenshot() to save a screenshot in
>   "/sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots/". Observe that this functionality
>   requires write permission (android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
>   in the AndroidManifest.xml of the application under test.

**From Emulator using Build server**

Alternative is using a buildserver like jenkins/hudson. There are plugins available to start the emulator during build and take screenshots from that emulator.

More information about that available on [this website listing the plugin details](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin).

Comment: So far i know Robotium is used for Android Native application testing  with screenshot capability but I mentioned about mobile web (Mobile Browser) site on my question.I never used Robotium for mobile web but used it for native app.

Answer (score 1):

Just to recap you need an API in order to capture automated screenshots of some websites using different **viewports**, and probably different **user-agent** headers as well, since you want it to look authentic for mobile devices.

I've personally made good experiences with the following two APIs:

- **screenshotlayer API** - https://screenshotlayer.com
- **url2png** - http://url2png.com

I'll just give you a quick hint on how you could capture screenshots using an iPhone `viewport` and `user-agent` (using the [screenshotlayer API](https://screenshotlayer.com) because it's free):

This is the API request URL you would use:

```bsh
http://api.screenshotlayer.com/api/capture
  ? access_key = YOUR_ACCESS_KEY
  & url = http://www.tumblr.com
  & user_agent = Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12A366 Safari/600.1.4&viewport=375x667   
  & viewport = 375x667
```

Now the API would return an iPhone 6 screenshot of the given URL (in our case *tumblr.com*).

For url2png it's quite similar. 
Hope this can help!

**EDIT**

What I forgot to mention - you can specify a `ftp' path to export the snapshot to

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [ApiFlash Screenshot API](https://apiflash.com/). The API is based on Chrome, so rendering is near pixel perfect and will always be up to date regarding web standards.

[image]

You can control the size of the screenshot using the `width` and `height` parameters. Here is a complete Java example that you can adapt to your particular problem.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String accessKey = "YOUR_ACCESS_KEY";
        String apiUrl = "https://api.apiflash.com/v1/urltoimage";
        URL url = new URL(String.format("%s?access_key=%s&url=google.com&width=800&height=600", apiUrl, accessKey));
        InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("screenshot.jpeg");

        byte[] b = new byte[2048];
        int length;

        while ((length = inputStream.read(b)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(b, 0, length);
        }

        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try [Browshot](http://browshot.com/) for a public website which has virtual mobile browsers (iPhone, iPad and Android). They have an API. There is no Java library (only Perl, PHP, Ruby and Python), but you could use the Java library from [Mashape](https://www.mashape.com/juliensobrier/website-screenshots-in-real-time#!documentation).